# Multiple openvpn clients on one openvpn server

Tags: security, vpn, openvpn

Can I have multiple openvpn clients connecting to a single openvpn server? The following setting works well for a **single** user

This is the server configuration (openvpn.conf)

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
secret openvpn-key.txt
ifconfig 192.168.2.1 192.168.2.2
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status server-tcp.log
verb 3
```

Here is the client config

```
dev tun
proto udp
remote HOSTNAME_IS_HERE 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
secret openvpn-key.txt
ifconfig 192.168.2.2 192.168.2.1
comp-lzo
verb 3
dhcp-option DNS 172.16.0.23
redirect-gateway def1
```

etc/sysconfig

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

Things work well until a second user tries to connect using the same VPN Key, etc. How do I allow multiple users?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/128132/can-generated-openvpn-keys-be-used-on-multiple-clients?lq=1

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you can.  By default, OpenVPN server doesn't allow multiple clients to connect with the same pair of cert/key;  each client must have its own cert/key with an **unique** common name.
However, multiple clients are allowed to connect to the OpenVPN server using the same pair of cert/key if `duplicate-cn` (allowing duplicate common name) is present in [OpenVPN server's configuration file](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/creating-configuration-files-for-server-and-clients/).

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can use openvpn for multiple clients, but you'll have to setup a [CA Authority](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#pki) and issue a unique key/cert to each client.  Or setup password-based authentication and use the `--duplicate-cn` option.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's fine if every client uses their own certificate, meaning that you need to issue a certificate based on the same common private-key to each client.

It's the certificate that is the actual authorization, since there are no login-credentials with OpenVPN.